# Is Ubuntu 16.04 good for gaming?

Tags: games

Is it recommended to use Ubuntu for gaming?
Seriously, I need to know if it worth the effort of installing Ubuntu on my PC.

I have a system with the following configuration: i7 2600, 8GB ram DDR3, SSD, Nvidia GTX970 MSI 4GB.

Comment: If your games are compatible with Ubuntu, they will work. Else not. There is no general final answer.

Comment: You need to give us some details of the games you are thinking of playing. As the current question stands, it is too vague and we can't possibly give you a good, let alone final, answer.

Comment: i play some steam, origin and Uplay games like "Need for speed 2015", "Battlefront", Rainbow six siege"

Comment: Yes. Gaming is fine on Ubuntu, however, not all games are available to run natively on Linux. You can run Windows games in a VM, or you can dual boot, or some may work under wine; or you can just not play them.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Ubuntu is worth the effort of installing on your PC, because it is very solid, secure and user-friendly. But Linux generally and Ubuntu particularly, is not the main target of PC games producers. Not yet, anyway. So there is a chance that your favourite games may not be available on Linux (although, we have to mention that there are several games playable only on Ubuntu).

So, if you want a final answer, here is mine: Do a dual-boot. On one partition, install a minimal Windows with some good security programs. On the other partition, install Ubuntu. Use Windows for gaming and Ubuntu for the rest of your activities. And thus you can have it all.

Did I said that this is my final answer? Oh, but no! Ubuntu is evolving. One day you will not need that Windows partition anymore!

Answer (score 4):

> "seriously, i need to know if it worth the effort of install ubuntu on my pc."

You could at least put effort into your question and specify what exactly you want to play. There are thousands of games out there.

You want a final answer? **No**.

But only because you asked whether it's *recommended* and I doubt anyone would speak out a general recommendation in this context today. It really depends what you want to do with Ubuntu. If you are going to install Steam, chances are many of your favourite games have already been ported to Linux, including all Valve titles. CS:Go runs really fine, so do all related titles. I'm confident that with Valve's efforts to steer clear from Microsoft and its Windows Market, Linux will play a significant role in gaming over the next few years.

Blizzard games on the other hand have not been ported and there are no known plans for doing so.

As for EA's Origin, there is also no official Ubuntu implementation.

Comment: Origin's game like "need for speed" and "battlefront" (the new one) work? and my Q is about the performance of gaming in ubuntu.. sorry for not be specifically in the question

Comment: @Saago Performance is a question of the code behind the application. If a Windows title is ported to Linux and the job is done poorly, you can expect a performance hit of easily 50%. Other games are showing promises, that their Vulcan implementation could perform a lot better than their DirectX counterpart, meaning that they could run better on Ubuntu with Vulcan than Windows with DirectX.

Comment: @Saago As for Need for Speed and Battlefront, just do a quick google search with *game title + Ubuntu* and find out whether there is a native application. In case of Need For Speed the first search results are instructions on how to use Wine on Ubuntu for running NFS. Wine is a wrapper for DirectX which lets you run Windows games under Ubuntu. As you might expect, the performance is nowhere near the native environment and some games might not even run at all.

Comment: Thanks you all, sorry for bad spelling and the unclear question :)

Comment: Will this change after Vulkan is supported by MIR?

Comment: @inf3rno Noone knows, but wevall sure hope so. We could finally get away from Direct X and therefore Windows.